# Custom repo NO_PUBKEY error

Tags: 16.04, apt, repository, gnupg

From apt-get update, I see following error:

```
W: GPG error: http://repo.domain.com/apt ./ Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 9B2C8CCCEC30B0E8
W: The repository 'http://repo.domain.com/apt ./ Release' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

That's our internal repo, I am trying to generate new key because Ubuntu Xenial doesn't allow digest SHA-1 anymore, but after I regenerate key, error above appears, what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

found solution:

```
1. go to repo server and repo directory
2. gpg --clearsign -o Release
3. rm Release.gpg
4. apt-ftparchive release . > Release
5. gpg --yes -abs -u $KEYNAME -o Release.gpg Release
```

No more NO_PUBKEY complain!